# Standart "File chooser" component in Android. How to?

Tags: android, file

How to run standart Android file chooser without creating own component with lists and adapters? I've searched about this question, but most of answers - about using file chooser libraries or creating own.
I need only dialog/activity for choosing file and returning it, and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.